# Conditional display of fields on views

Tags: views

There's a problem I still couldn't find a good solution with Views, I'm using Drupal 7. I have a view form that searches for apartments for rent in a specific location. There are two combos in the form: one listing the cities, and another combo listing the districs. I want the district combo to be shown only when the value selected on the city combo is "New York", for example.